# Taylor series of $f(x)=\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}+e^x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}+e^x$$

The task is to find a Taylor series expansion around the point $c=2$ and to find an interval of convergence.$\\$

I've managed to do the first part, but I'm not sure if it's correct or how to find an interval. The expansion I've calculated is $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\left(\binom{-2}{n}\frac{1}{3^{n+\frac{1}{2}}}+\frac{e^2}{n!}\right)\cdot(x-2)^n}$$

Any hints would be helpful.

Comment: Can you explain some of your calculation steps?

Comment: @jacmeird Firstly, I took  $x=y+2$ so I get to calculate an expansion around $c=2$. My function is now $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\cdot(1+\frac{y}{3})^{-2}+e^2\cdot e^y$. Then, I used formulas for series of $(1+y)^\alpha$ and $e^y$ and later returned $x=y-2$.

Comment: Okay, some mistakes, look at the hint below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g (x)=f (x+2) $.

$g $ is the derivative of $h:x\mapsto e^{x+2}-\frac {1}{3+x} .$

FOR $x $ st $|x/3|<1$, we have

$$h (x)=\frac{-1}{3}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} (-1)^k (\frac {x}{3})^k$$
$$+e^2\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac {x^k}{k!} $$

and by integration, we get

$$g (x)=g (0)-\frac {1}{3}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^k\frac {x^{k+1}}{3^k (k+1)}+e^2\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac {x^k}{k!} $$
$$=1/9+e^2+\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}(\frac {(-1)^k}{3^k.k}+\frac {e^2}{k!})x^k $$
finally

$$f (x)=g (x-2) $$ for $x $ such that $|x-2|<3$.

Comment: @Ashkan Done. thx.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it completely!

Answer (score 1):

Hint : $$g(x) =  f(x + 2)=\frac{1}{(3+x)^2}+e^{x+2}$$ $$ = \frac{1}{9} \frac{1}{(1+ \frac{x}{3})^2}+ e^2 e^{x}$$

Now find Taylor series and its convergence radius of function $g$ about $x=0$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm still unable to find the convergence radius. I can't calculate $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$ or $limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$...

Comment: @iskra For the Radius, you have two series. the second has +infinity. the first is geometric.

Comment: You know the  convergence domain (radius) of $e^x$ and $\frac{1}{(3+x)^2}$ centered zero, right?

Now the convergence domain of $g$ is  the intersection  of those domains which is minimum of radius  @iskra